# "No bootable device" message after dual-installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, bios

it's me again.

I just solved a freezing problem (turned out to be a faulty RAM stick) thanks to this great community, so I thought you guys would like to tackle another issue I have. My computer is an Acer Aspire, like the one in the link: https://www.komplett.se/product/752070#technical-details

So I just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, using a USB installer. The computer has a 1TB SATA drive. The partitions were as follows: Windows (C) - 500GB, EFI - 250 MB, Recovery - 18GB, and a new 100GB partition for Ubuntu. There's also about 400 GB that's unallocated.

All was fine and dandy throughout the installation, and I rebooted the computer. That's when I'm told there's no bootable device available. I can still boot the live Ubuntu on the USB, and there I can still access the harddrive.

In BIOS I've made sure the harddrive is on top of the boot priority order. I've tried finding a way to disable secure boot but to no avail - despite setting a password and rebooting.

Link showing BIOS settings and live USB folder structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34WSR.jpg

It's strange how neither Ubuntu nor Windows shows up in the boot menu, seeing as the drive seems OK? It's probably a partition error on my part.

Thanks,
/Nils

Comment: Try to place "EFI" at the top of your boot order list.

Comment: I just did, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from live USB
2. Mount your hdd to /mnt/disk (create if needed)
3. mount --bind /dev /mnt/disk/dev
4. chroot /mnt/disk /bin/bash
5. update-grub2
   If it shows all your installed OS, try to reboot and see if it works.

If it doesn't try do the samp p.1 to p.4, but then you need to install grub to your disk
sudo grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda